# Good Oracle role for developer's personal use?

Tags: oracle, roles

We're installing some Oracle XE servers (the free one) on people's desktops for development use.

What's a good default role to assign to these developers?  Since these instances contain scratch data only, data security is not a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the developers to be able to do anything grant the DBA on the development DB.  Of course there is a risk with this; if they develop and run the code as themselves they will not address the security needs of the application.

If you want the developers to work with the security context of the application grant them the same roles that the application has in Prod.

So; if you want them to be able to do anything on the Dev instance but still code in the same security context as on Prod, create 2 users for them.  The first is there usual users with the same rights as the code will execute under in Prod and the second is a DBA user with teh DBA role.

Its odd to some people who are used to the Windows approach (where a domain admin user reads email, browses the web, etc with domain admin rights) but very familiar to a Unix user who redas email as a low level user but can SUDO if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer all I ask for on dev databases is the SYSTEM password, as well as enough space in some tablespace(s) to create my objects. That gives me enough to get going - I can create my users, grant them the access they need, and get started developing.